# Last Runtime 9020 returned by Windows Scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I implemented an update process for a piece of software using the Windows scheduler. It worked great until lately. For some reason the task entered in the Windows Scheduler is not executed anymore.

I suspect that the configuration of the target system changed, but I do not know in which way. The command `schtasks /query /V /FO list` returns:

```
HostName:                             someHostName
TaskName:                             update myProgram

Next Run Time:                        never
Status:                                
Logon Mode:                           13:03:00 16.02.2010
Last Run Time:                        9020  
Last Result:                          
Creato:                               system
Task To Run:                          c:\myUpdate.cmd

Start In:                             N/A
Comment:                              N/A
Scheduled Task State:                 Enabled
Idle Time:                            Disabled

Run As User:                          NT Authoring /System
Delete Task If Not Rescheduled:       Enabled
Stop Task If Runs X Hours and X Mins: 72:00:00
Schedule:                             Enable
Schedule Type:                        One time only
Start Time:                           N/A
Start Date:                           N/A
End Date:                             N/A
Days:                                 N/A
Months:                               N/A
Repeat: Every:                        N/A
Repeat: Until: Time:                  N/A
Repeat: Until: Duration:              N/A
Repeat: Stop If Still Running:        N/A
```

The task was inserted at 16.02.10 13:02:14, and therefore, it should have ran at 13:03:00 16.02.2010, but `Last Runtime` shows `9020`. Does anybody know what that means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the executable started by the scheduler was missing a DLL and therefore could not executed. So I guess 9020 is some sort of error code, although I could not find it in [the reference](http://www.hiteksoftware.com/knowledge/articles/049.htm).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error code 9020 returned after my scheduled job would run and what it turned out to be in my case was a config file that exe was using that had **XML syntax error**. 
Once my xml was validated and well-formed my job was able to run/start.

Answer (score 0):

the error is "MSG_EXEC_FAILURE" from cmdmsg.h, I think

Description:

```
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case closing the existing daemon fixed.

- had an exe running/listening to MQ msgs.
- made a fix to dll and deployed
- tried to start the new exe with new dll, in the same box where the old one was running.
- Produced 9020 error.
- So, started the listener else where so clients would not be affected
- shut down the old instance and started the new instance with now issues.

Comment: This was already answered. By the OP, explaining that they were missing a DLL. And answered 6 years ago. What you observed with your issue has nothing to do with the OP's original problem.

Comment: My case was version of dll was different. Thought it will provide quick reference to someone in a crisis time.